# Sympy solution to evaluating the derivative of the function on x

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, derivative

I am new to sympy and working on evaluating a derivative. I have been following e.g. this video which walks through derivatives in Sympy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSq3JexqZ5k - but even following their example closely my code returns errors. Here is my problem:

Write the following function:

```
def myDerivative(w1, w2, x):
```

myDerivative() must evaluate the derivative of the function `f(x) = w1 * x^3 + w2 * x - 1` on point x.

Comment: it is better just to explain what is it you want to do. As in, I have this function f(x), and show what it is, and I want to find its derivative and then evaluate the answer at x=1 or something like this. Then someone can show how to do it.  No code is needed to show.

Comment: Thanks Nasser I have edited it to present the problem more clearly and without confusing code.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I think I've found a solution, for anyone interested. My mistake was in using `x` for the output of `sy.Symbol('x')` and also as a parameter (the two references to `x` were being confused). So I changed the parameter corresponding to the point at which to evaluate the derivative to `pt`. I think this may be the solution...

```
import sympy as sy

def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')

    # Define original equation
    def f(x, w1, w2):
        return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1

    # Get derivative of f(x)
    def df(x, w1, w2):
        return sy.diff(f(x, w1, w2), x)

    # Evaluate at point x
    return df(x, w1, w2).subs(x, pt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for a *vanilla* Python solution to understand what's happening, here it is

```py
def derivative(w1, w2, x):
    term1_derivative = 3 * w1 * x**2
    term2_derivative = w2
    term3_derivative = 0 # Derivative of a constant is 0
    total_derivative = term1_derivative + term2_derivative + term3_derivative
    return total_derivative
```